# Mocking HttpRequest in ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, moq

I've seen a lot of similar threads but none that actually address my particular situation.

I'm writing unit tests in ASP.NET 4.0 web application (ASP.NET Forms, not MVC). There are several spots in the code where I call the `ServerVariables` collection to call variables like `REMOTE_ADDR`. Since my unit tests do not actually initiate `HttpRequests` when executing my code, things like `ServerVariables` are `Null` and therefore error when I try to call `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")`

All the solutions I've found to address this issue refer to MVC and so they assume that `HttpRequest` derives from `HttpRequestBase`, which it does in MVC but not in ASP.NET Forms.

I tried using `Moq` but you can't mock a sealed class, and `HttpRequest` is unfortunately sealed with no interface.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`HttpRequestBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.aspx) and [`HttpRequestWrapper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestwrapper.aspx) classes can be used with a bit of work.

Wherever you currently access `HttpContext.Current.Request` -- or just plain `Page.Request` -- you'll need to use an injectable instance of `HttpRequestBase` instead. Then you'll need to inject a different subclass of `HttpRequestBase` depending on whether you're testing or live.

- For live code, you'd probably inject an `HttpRequestWrapper` instance that wraps `HttpContext.Current.Request`:

  ```
  var liveRequest = new HttpRequestWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Request);
  ```
- For test code, you'd need to create and inject your own mock subclass of `HttpRequestBase`. Presumably Moq can do that for you on-the-fly.

Comment: Thanks! I am a little hesitant to change the live code though. The live code is currently stable and very complex but was built without a unit testing framework. I'm trying to slowly introduce unit testing into the mix with a new feature I'm adding. I'm worried unit testing will be hard to sell to the rest of my team if I have to change the stable code to conform to the unit tests - even though in test-driven development it would have been written that way from the start.

Comment: +1 for a good answer though. I may still end up going down this road.

Comment: I ended up going a different route and using WatiN for the unit testing. WatiN tests it from the UI layer and so doesn't need to mock the HttpRequest. Thanks for your help. I'm marking yours as the answer anyway since it did in fact answer the question regardless of whether or not that's the direction I went.