# Read Custom HttpHeaders using C#

Tags: c#, httpclient

I am uploading a file to server. I have set `FileName` as custom header into my `HttpRequestMessage`. I am unable to read this header on server side.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:54616/");

    HttpContent fileContent = new StreamContent(fs);
    HttpRequestMessage httpMsg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "Api/FileHandler");
    httpMsg.Content = fileContent;
    httpMsg.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

    httpMsg.Content.Headers.Add("FileName", Path.GetFileName(file));

    var httpTask = client.SendAsync(httpMsg).Result;
}
```

On Server Side:

```
var input = Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
var allHeaders = Request.Content.Headers.GetValues("FileName").ToList();
```

> It throws InvalidOperation exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract custom header value in Web API message handler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967457/how-to-extract-custom-header-value-in-web-api-message-handler)

Comment: @wizkid Not a duplicate, I have similar code as suggested in the answer there but when running I get `InvalidOperation Exception`

Comment: Use `Request.Headers`

Answer (score 2):

You have to realize that `HttpContentHeaders` is wrapping the headers that are **Content** headers. You cannot expect to add your custom ('FileName') header to it and read it later.

Use the regular `Headers` collection instead:

```
// write
httpMsg.Headers.Add("FileName", Path.GetFileName(file));

// read
var fileHeaders = Request.Headers.GetValues("FileName").ToList();
```

Or, if you insist on `HttpContentHeaders`, use its `ContentLocation` property which returns a `Uri`:

```
// write
httpMsg.Content.Headers.ContentLocation = new Uri(file);

// read
Uri file = Request.Content.Headers.ContentLocation;
```

Also, before reading your header value, it's always recommended to check whether that header exists at all (so you'll avoid the Exception):

```
if (Request.Headers.Contains("FileName"))
    fileHeaders = Request.Headers.GetValues("FileName").ToList();
```