# How to see what dataType is requested by an ajax call in asp.net api

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, api

In an ASP.NET API, how do you get what datatype is requested by an ajax call when you set requested datatype in ajax like so?

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: params,
    dataType: "xml",
    type: "GET",
    statusCode: {
        200: function (data) {

            }
        }
```

Then, in my controller, I would like to get whether I requested XML or JSON.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain what you want to know ?

Comment: Just edited the question. So, in the controller, I want to be able to see what I typed in the ajax request after dataType: ("xml" or "JSON")

Comment: the datatype value simply add the `content-type` header in your request. Your controller will check this header to choose what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This goes in the accept http header - asp.net webapi will do most of the content type negotiation for you - see [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation)

jQuery will put it in the accept header as application/json or application/xml and you can manually get it out of the request.Headers

Comment: True. In  Request.Headers.Accept.First().MediaType to be precise.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, this information will translate as the 'Accept' header in you HTTP request. I'm not 100% sure as this might also only be info kept by JQuery to better decode the answer. In anyway, there is also an `accepts` parameter in the Ajax settings which sets the 'Accept' header of the request for sure. JQuery's documentation however says that the `accepts` parameter defaults to a value depending on the `dataType` parameter, so I would be tempted to say my first guess is right.

To retrieve the headers from the controller, simply call :

```
IEnumerable<string> headerValues = request.Headers.GetValues("MyCustomID");
var id = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
```

(for error handling on this method see [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14967548/4064630))